# StandardTreeItem change font of the title?

Tags: sapui5

I have a multi leveled `sap.m.Tree` and I really want to change either the font or the item color of the `sap.m.StandardTreeItem` based on some input data.

For example if the String input equals "1", then the first node should get yellow text etc. .

Is there any convenient way to access the node cause I only seem to get the top level nodes with

```
var treeItems = oTree.getItems();
```

I figured I can just search using jQuery for class '`sapMCbBg`' but it appears rather unappealing. If somebody has better ideas I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control to handle this. Here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
      .node1 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"myControls": "./"}'>
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns="sap.m" 
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns:my="myControls">

    <Tree items="{/}">
      <items>
        <my:StandardTreeItem title="{text}" />
      </items>
    </Tree>
    </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script>
      jQuery.sap.declare("myControls.StandardTreeItem");

      sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
        'sap/m/StandardTreeItem'
      ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, StandardTreeItem) {
        "use strict";

        var oData = [{
          text: "Node1",
          nodes: [{
            text: "Node1-1"
          }]
        }, {
          text: "Node2",
          nodes: [{
            text: "Node2-1"
          }]
        }];

        StandardTreeItem.extend("myControls.StandardTreeItem", {
          renderer: {},
          onAfterRendering: function() {
            if (StandardTreeItem.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
              StandardTreeItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, null);
            }
            var text = this.getBindingContext().getObject().text;
            if (text.indexOf('Node1') === 0) {
              this.$().find(".sapMLIBContent").addClass("node1");
            }
          }
        });


        var oController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
          onInit: function(oEvent) {
            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(oData));
          },
        });

        return oController;
      });

      var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
      });

      oView.placeAt('content');

    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/zijajas/edit?html,js,output